# Relaton between IB, α and ICO near cut-off region for a bjt in CE mode

Tags: bjt

I am reading Electronics and Devices by Boylestad and it says:

$$
\begin{align}
I_E &= I_C + I_B  &(1)\\
I_C &= \alpha I_E + I_{CO}  &(2) \\
I_E &= \alpha I_E + I_{CO} + I_B  &(3)
\end{align}
$$
Is equation 3 valid for all regions of operation?

because if equation 3 is valid near cutoff region, if \$I_B\$ is decreased to zero, 
either \$\alpha\$ has to increase or \$I_{CO}\$ should increase.
Also is there any relationship between \$I_B\$, \$\alpha\$  and \$I_{CO}\$?
How to connect the concept that, if there is no base current, no collector current flows in the transistor?

Comment: Hi ibsen, I fixed your equations. This site supports [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can have a look at the link or just see the edited answer to understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Equation 3 is totally derivable from eq2 and eq1 so the question really is should equation 2 be valid in all regions of operation.

In detail, equation 2 is saying collector current comprises the (large normally) fraction of emitter current that flows through the collector + leakage current through the collector-base reversed junction.

And, as far as I remember this is valid under in all regions of operation that I can think of.

[This](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KacQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=Ic+%3D+alpha+Ie+%2B+Ico&source=bl&ots=12mqt05PGh&sig=_5eSPNnQEKEQohKu1P2GaL2F4sk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VEnmU8jSLui47AbmhYCgDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Ic%20%3D%20alpha%20Ie%20%2B%20Ico&f=false) page might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

"*How to connect the concept that, if there is no base current, no collector current flows in the transistor?*"

The well-known equation **Ie=Ic+Ib** must not be misunderstood. It simply says that the current Ie (caused by the voltage Vbe) is split into two parts: A very small current Ib and a much larger current Ic. With other words: You must not ask "What happens with Ic when Ib=0 ?"because such a question assumes that Ib would be the cause of Ic (which is not the case).

In general, such an equation gives the mathematical relation beween some quantities (in this case: currents) only, but it doesn`t tell you anything about cause and effect.